# HighCharts API for Deprecated Versions

Tags: highcharts

Does anyone know if the HighCharts 2.* API documentation is still available online anywhere since the release of HighCharts 3?  I have not upgraded yet and I could really use access to the API doc for version 2.3.5.  In particular, I'd like access to the exporting module documentation from HighCharts 2.3.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately previous documentation are not available, but in current docs in paramters description you can notice version (right side), which is compability with this option.

**Edit:**
Highcharts now includes an API folder when downloading a deprecated version https://code.highcharts.com/zips/Highcharts-5.0.0.zip. But the API folder is only on version 5 and up.

Comment: I don't see an api folder for version 6.1.1

Comment: I downloaded 6.0.0 and there is no api folder

Comment: yeah it's missing for most of the versions bummer we can't easily access old api docs here is a link to version 6 https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/6.0.5/plotOptions.xrange

Comment: I mean sure I understand they try to get their users to update but sometimes is not possible and there should be a way to easily see older API